# Targeted for x64 would sometimes result in very bad performance than for anycpu

Tags: f#

These are 2 functions, `fun1` takes 1 parameter, `fun2` takes 4 extra useless parameters. When I targeted for x64, `fun1` takes 4s but `fun2` takes less than 1s. If I targeted for anycpu, then both take less than 1s.

There is a similar question I asked here
[why Seq.iter is 2x faster than for loop if target is for x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209729/why-seq-iter-is-2x-faster-than-for-loop-in-this-case)

It is compiled in .Net 4.5 Visual Studio 2012, F# 3.0, run in windows 7 x64

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

type Position =
    {
        a: int
        b: int
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let fun1 (pos: Position[]) =  //<<<<<<<< here
        let functionB x y z = 4

        Array.fold2 (fun acc x y -> acc + int64 (functionB x x y)) 0L pos pos

    let fun2 (pos: Position[]) u v w x =  //<<<<<<<< here
        let functionB x y z = 4

        Array.fold2 (fun acc x y -> acc + int64 (functionB x x y)) 0L pos pos



    let s = {a=2;b=3}
    let pool = [|s;s;s|]

    let test1 n =
        let mutable x = 0L
        for i in 1 .. n do
            x <- fun1 pool

    let test2 n =
        let mutable x = 0L
        for i in 1 .. n do
            x <- fun2 pool 1 2 3 4

    let sw = new Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    test2 10000000
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed)

    sw.Restart()
    test1 10000000
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed)


    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: I can repro with VS2012 RTM – your first code takes ~4 seconds, your second is < 1 second. Also, it does take a full extra four parameters for there to be any difference; adding three extra still takes ~4 seconds.

Comment: Intriguingly there is no obvious reason for the speedup - I compared the disassembly and it is identical except in the second case more instructions are added to load the extra parameters which I would have expected to slow it down.

Comment: Weird. They're practically the same for me (~4)...actually the second one consistently takes a hair longer. (VS2012 RTM .NET 4.5)

Comment: Is the output type of your F# project set to 'Class Library'?

Comment: @Daniel : My repro was done as a standalone x64 app (no C#, no class libraries). Maybe this is a pathological case for x64 and it's fine with x86? Was your test x64?

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, this is x64. I tried it as a standalone app—same results: neither take less than 4 secs.

Answer (score 2):

*This isn't a complete answer, it is first diagnostics of the problem.*

I can reproduce the behaviour with the same configuration. If you turn on F# Interactive 64-bit in `Tools -> Options -> F# Tools -> F# Interactive`, you can observe the same behaviour there.

Diferrent from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209729/why-seq-iter-is-2x-faster-than-for-loop-if-target-is-for-x64?lq=1), x64 jitter isn't a problem. It turns out *"Generate tail calls"* option in Project property causes considerable slowdown of `test1` compared to `test2`. If you turn off that option, two cases are at similar speeds.

On the other hand, you can use `inline` keyword on `fun1` so that tail call isn't needed. Two examples are comparable in execution time again no matter `fun2` is inlined or not.

That said, it is weird that adding `tail.` opcode to `fun1` makes it much slower than (doing the same with) `fun2`. You may contact F# team for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is almost certainly a quirk of the JITer. It also explains the inconsistent results. This is a common problem with micro-benchmarking tests like this. Perform one or more redundant executions of the methods in order to compile the whole thing behind the scenes, and time the last one. They will be identical.

You can get more bizarre results than this due to this quirk.